# A parallelogram and a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

The perimeter of a parallelogram $ABCD$ is $30$ $cm$. If $D$ and $M$ which is the midpoint of $\overline{DC}$ lie on the circle with diameter $\overline{AB}$, what is the perimeter of $ABMD$?

[image]

We know that $\overline{AB}\parallel \overline{CD}$ since $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, so as $DM\in CD,$ then $\overline{AB}\parallel \overline{DM}$. $M\ne C$ so $\overline{BM}$ cannot be parallel to $\overline{AD}$ which makes the quadrilateral $ABMD$ a trapezoid. Even more, since $A,B,M,D$ lie on $k$, the trapezoid is inscribed, so $\overline{AD}=\overline{BM}$. We have $$AO=BO=\dfrac12AB=\dfrac12CD=DM=CM.$$ What else? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You show that all triangles in your figure are équilatéral

Comment: The parallelogram is made of four equal triangle as you shown in figure. you remove one so the area of $ABMD=\frac 34 (30)=22.5$

Comment: You may want to use the radii so $DM=AO=OM=OD$ gives one of the many equilateral triangles and also $OM \parallel AD$ and $AO \parallel DM$  to give $OM=AD$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\overline{DM}$ is congruent to the radius of the circle, $\triangle DMO$ is equilateral.  By symmetry, $\angle AOD\cong\angle BOM$, so those are both $60^\circ$ and the other two triangles inside the circle must be equilateral as well.

Therefore, each of the six line segments that comprise the perimeter of the triangle are congruent, so each has measure $\frac16\cdot30\text{cm}=5\text{cm}$.  Since the trapezoid is made of five such congruent segments, its perimeter is $25\text{cm}$.

Answer (score 0):

Along diameter AB of 2 units ( each side of equilateral triangle unit= 5 ) the circle construction gives a trapezium . It comprises three equilateral triangles.

By drawing the two parallels the angle enclosed at C is $60^{\circ}$. In the new situation (top half of regular hexagon ) six units are replaced by five units so reducing perimeter to $ 5\times 5=25.$